# How to get real IP from behind Sucuri firewall

Tags: geoip

I have a Magento store on an Ngix behind Sucuri firewall and we hide prices if the IP is outside of UK. 
A bruteforce attack was bypassing the firewall so the hosting added the following rules to prevent bypass:

```
     location / {
            allow 192.88.134.0/23;
           allow 185.93.228.0/22;
          allow 2a02:fe80::/29;
          allow 66.248.200.0/22;
          deny all;
           # Existing NGINX rules
            }
```

This works fine except that all IPs are transalted as the firewall one based in UK. To get the real IP Sucuri suggested to add the following:

```
  # Define header with original client IP
  real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
  # Define trusted Firewall IPs
  set_real_ip_from 192.88.134.0/23;
  set_real_ip_from 185.93.228.0/22;
  set_real_ip_from 66.248.200.0/22;
   set_real_ip_from 2a02:fe80::/29; # this line can be removed if IPv6 is 
  disabled
```

This second rule causes a problem. Once the IP is translated and if it is different than the allowed Sucuri IP addresses, the requests is restricted with 403 Forbidden error.

Is it impossible to have the store behind a firewall and still get the real IP. I am sure that this is not the only store in the world behind a firewall, which needs to server different content depending on the IP. 
The code in  Magento that gets the IP of the client is something like this:

```
        $geoIP = Mage::getSingleton('geoip/country'); 

        if ($geoIP->isCountryAllowed()) {....
```

Any alternative? SOlution? My hosting provider is useless..

Comment: Does that mean the users' real IP is now received  in the $_SERVER variable under the header $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] whereas the $_SERVER[“REMOTE_ADDR”] is the WAF IP(Web Application Firewall IP) - If yes, Magento can be configured to work correctly.

Comment: Can you elaborate and explain how please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all those who come across the same issue and try to get an answer from sucuri or hopeless hosting providers like siteground, this is what worked for me. I put the following code at the very beginning of Magento index.php:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_SUCURI_CLIENTIP']))
 {
     $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_SUCURI_CLIENTIP'];
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

We hit the same issue, when trying to apply the suggested "Block Sucuri Bypass" as well as for a couple of clients that use Stackpath.

```
location / {
    # Block everything that isn't sucuri
    allow 192.88.134.0/23;
    allow 185.93.228.0/22;
    allow 2a02:fe80::/29;
    allow 66.248.200.0/22;
    deny all;
    
    # other nginx config
}
```

As this was below the already configured:

```
# Define header with original client IP
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
# Define trusted IPs
set_real_ip_from 192.88.134.0/23;
set_real_ip_from 185.93.228.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 66.248.200.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 2a02:fe80::/29;
```

## Magento 1

So long as the code uses the core method:

```php
Mage::helper('core/http')->getRemoteAddr()
```

You can add a list of headers to `app/etc/local.xml` inside of `config->global` node that are used to determine the "real" ip. Something like:

```xml
<remote_addr_headers>
    <header1>HTTP_X_SUCURI_CLIENTIP</header1>
    <header2>HTTP_X_REAL_IP</header2>
    <header3>HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR</header3>
</remote_addr_headers>
```

Then you can remove the `real_ip_header` and `set_real_ip_from` from the nginx config. Allowing all traffic not from Sucuri to be blocked and still able to obtain the true IP within magento. You can test this with something like:

```
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
require MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/bootstrap.php';
require_once $mageFilename;

Mage::app('admin');
print_r($_SERVER);
echo 'address: '.Mage::helper('core/http')->getRemoteAddr();
```

## Magento 2

This appears to a little harder, I haven't dug as deep but on initial look.

- `vendor/magento/framework/Session/Validator.php`
  is sensitive to configuration, on if it should use: `http_x_forwarded_for` or `remote_addr`
- `vendor/magento/framework/HTTP/PhpEnvironment/Request.php:725`
  has the method `getClientIp` which appears to use the first it finds from `HTTP_CLIENT_IP`, `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`, `REMOTE_ADDR`
- `vendor/magento/magento2-base/pub/errors/processor.php:312`
  had the method `_getClientIp` which uses `REMOTE_ADDR` and if that isn't found returns `undefined`

If we exclude the error page. We can configure Magento to look for additional headers, by passing the arguments into the class `Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress`.
As this configuration is installation specific, I have done this in the file: `app/etc/custom/di.xml` this allows us to override/append the base DI for Magento.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="alternativeHeaders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sucuri" xsi:type="string">HTTP_X_SUCURI_CLIENTIP</item>
                <item name="stackpath" xsi:type="string">HTTP_X_SP_FORWARDED_IP</item>
                <item name="real_ip" xsi:type="string">HTTP_X_REAL_IP</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

After doing this you will need to re-compile Magento and flush cache.
Magento will then search for the headers specified here first, before falling back to core behaviour.